Webrtc Connection not fully COMPLETED and Data channel state not open
I created a Flutter app and used Google WebRTC in Android native, avoiding the flutter_webrtc package. When I connect one device (Peer A) to another device (Peer B), on Peer A, the connection states are: Signaling state: STABLE and ICE connection state: COMPLETED. On Peer B, the connection states are: Signaling state: STABLE and ICE connection state: CONNECTED. Additionally, the Data Channel state is 'connecting'
MainActivity.kt
package com.example.flutter_web_rtc

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.models.IceCandidateModel
import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.models.MessageModel
import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.utils.DataConverter
import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.utils.FileMetaDataType
import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.utils.NewMessageInterface
import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.utils.PeerConnectionObserver

import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.utils.RTCAudioManager
import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.utils.ReceiverListner
import com.google.gson.Gson
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import org.webrtc.DataChannel
import org.webrtc.IceCandidate
import org.webrtc.MediaStream
import org.webrtc.SessionDescription


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() , NewMessageInterface ,ReceiverListner{
    private var granted = false
    private val CHANNEL = "SendToAndroid"
    private var PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    private var userName:String?=null
    private var socketRepository: SocketRepository?=null
    private var rtcClient : RTCClient?=null
    private val TAG = "WebRtc_native_calls"
    private var target:String = ""
    private val gson = Gson()
    private var isMute = false
    private var isCameraPause = false
    private val rtcAudioManager by lazy { RTCAudioManager.create(this) }
    private var isSpeakerMode = true
    private var CallerName:String = ""
    private var dataChannel : DataChannel? = null

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                when (call.method) {
                    "handlePeerAction" -> {
                        val peerName = call.argument<String>("peerName")
                        val targetPeer = call.argument<String>("targetPeer")
                        val action = call.argument<String>("action")

                        // Handle the method call
                        handlePeerAction(peerName, targetPeer, action, result)
                    }
                    else -> result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
            }

    private fun handlePeerAction(peerName: String?, targetPeer: String?, action: String?, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        when (action) {
            "addPeer" -> {
                // Handle the addPeer action
                if(granted && peerName != null){
                    userName = peerName
                    init();
                }
                result.success("Peer added: $peerName")
            }
            "connect" -> {
                // Handle the connect action
                if (granted && targetPeer != null) {
                    startCall(targetPeer)
                    target = targetPeer
                }
                result.success("Connected to peer: $targetPeer")
            }
            "p2p-check" -> {
                    Log.d("check p2p ","channel working..")

                    rtcClient?.checkConnectionStatus()
                sendTextToDataChannel("hello")

            }
            else -> result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Action not supported", null)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Check and request permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ), PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            // Initialize PeerConnectionFactory
            granted  = true;
            socketRepository = SocketRepository(this)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            var allPermissionsGranted = true

            for (grantResult in grantResults) {
                if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    allPermissionsGranted = false
                    break
                }
            }
            if (allPermissionsGranted) {
                // Initialize PeerConnectionFactory after permissions are granted
                granted  = true;
                socketRepository = SocketRepository(this)
            } else {
                Log.e("Permissions", "Permissions denied.")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun init(){

        userName?.let { socketRepository?.initSocket(it) }
        rtcClient = RTCClient(application,userName!!,socketRepository!!, object : PeerConnectionObserver() {
            override fun onIceCandidate(p0: IceCandidate?) {
                super.onIceCandidate(p0)
                rtcClient?.addIceCandidate(p0)
                val candidate = hashMapOf(
                    "sdpMid" to p0?.sdpMid,
                    "sdpMLineIndex" to p0?.sdpMLineIndex,
                    "sdpCandidate" to p0?.sdp
                )

                socketRepository?.sendMessageToSocket(
                    MessageModel("ice_candidate",userName,target,candidate)
                )
            }
            override fun onAddStream(p0: MediaStream?) {
                super.onAddStream(p0)
                Log.d(TAG, "onAddStream: $p0")

            }

            override fun onDataChannel(p0: DataChannel?) {
                super.onDataChannel(p0)
                dataChannel = p0
            }
        })
        rtcAudioManager.setDefaultAudioDevice(RTCAudioManager.AudioDevice.SPEAKER_PHONE)

    }

    private fun startCall(targetUserNameEt: String){
        socketRepository?.sendMessageToSocket(MessageModel(
            "start_call",userName,targetUserNameEt,null
        ))
    }




    override fun onNewMessage(message: MessageModel) {
        Log.d(TAG,message.toString());
        when(message.type){
            "call_response"-> {
                if (message.data == "user is not online") {
                    Log.d(TAG, "user is not reachable");

                } else {
                    rtcClient?.call(target)

                }
            }
            "offer_received" ->{

                val session = SessionDescription(
                    SessionDescription.Type.OFFER,
                    message.data.toString()
                )
                rtcClient?.onRemoteSessionReceived(session)
                rtcClient?.answer(message.name!!)
                target = message.name!!
                }

            "answer_received" ->{
                val session = SessionDescription(
                    SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER,
                    message.data.toString()
                )
                rtcClient?.onRemoteSessionReceived(session)

            }

            "ice_candidate"->{
                    try {
                        val receivingCandidate = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(message.data),
                            IceCandidateModel::class.java)
                        rtcClient?.addIceCandidate(IceCandidate(receivingCandidate.sdpMid,
                            Math.toIntExact(receivingCandidate.sdpMLineIndex.toLong()),receivingCandidate.sdpCandidate))
                    }catch (e:Exception){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }

            }

        }


    private fun sendTextToDataChannel(text:String){
        sendBufferToDataChannel(DataConverter.convertToBuffer(FileMetaDataType.META_DATA_TEXT,text))
        sendBufferToDataChannel(DataConverter.convertToBuffer(FileMetaDataType.TEXT,text))
    }

    private fun sendBufferToDataChannel(buffer: DataChannel.Buffer){
        dataChannel?.send(buffer)

    }

    override fun onDataRecived(it: DataChannel.Buffer) {
            val data = ByteArray(it.data.remaining())
            it.data.get(data)
            val textDataString = String(data,Charsets.UTF_8)
            Log.d("data_Received", textDataString)
    }


}

RTCClient.kt
package com.example.flutter_web_rtc

import android.app.Application
import android.util.Log
import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.models.MessageModel
import com.example.flutter_web_rtc.utils.ReceiverListner
import org.webrtc.AudioTrack
import org.webrtc.CameraVideoCapturer
import org.webrtc.DataChannel
import org.webrtc.DefaultVideoDecoderFactory
import org.webrtc.DefaultVideoEncoderFactory
import org.webrtc.EglBase
import org.webrtc.IceCandidate
import org.webrtc.MediaConstraints
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection.IceConnectionState
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection.SignalingState
import org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory
import org.webrtc.SdpObserver
import org.webrtc.SessionDescription
import org.webrtc.VideoTrack


class RTCClient(
    private val application: Application,
    private val username: String,
    private val socketRepository: SocketRepository,
    private val observer: PeerConnection.Observer

) {

    init {
        initPeerConnectionFactory(application)

    }

    private val eglContext = EglBase.create()
    private val peerConnectionFactory by lazy { createPeerConnectionFactory() }
    private val iceServer = listOf(
        PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:iphone-stun.strato-iphone.de:3478").createIceServer(),
        PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:openrelay.metered.ca:80"),
        PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:openrelay.metered.ca:80","openrelayproject","openrelayproject"),
        PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:openrelay.metered.ca:443","openrelayproject","openrelayproject"),
        PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:openrelay.metered.ca:443?transport=tcp","openrelayproject","openrelayproject"),

        )

    private val peerConnection by lazy { createPeerConnection(observer) }

    var reciverListener : ReceiverListner? = null


    private val dataChannelObserver = object : DataChannel.Observer{
        override fun onBufferedAmountChange(p0: Long) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onStateChange() {
            val state =
                peerConnection!!.createDataChannel("dataChannelLabel", DataChannel.Init()).state()
            when (state) {
                DataChannel.State.CONNECTING -> Log.d("PeerConnection", "data Channel State: Connecting")
                DataChannel.State.OPEN -> Log.d("PeerConnection", "data Channel State Open")
                DataChannel.State.CLOSING -> Log.d("PeerConnection", "data Channel State Closing")
                DataChannel.State.CLOSED -> Log.d("PeerConnection", "data Channel State: Closed")
            }
        }

        override fun onMessage(p0: DataChannel.Buffer?) {
            p0?.let { reciverListener?.onDataRecived(it) }
        }

    }

    private fun initPeerConnectionFactory(application: Application) {
        val peerConnectionOption = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(application)
            .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
            .setFieldTrials("WebRTC-H264HighProfile/Enabled/")
            .createInitializationOptions()

        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(peerConnectionOption)
    }

    private fun createPeerConnectionFactory(): PeerConnectionFactory {
        return PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(
                DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
                    eglContext.eglBaseContext,
                    true,
                    true
                )
            )
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(eglContext.eglBaseContext))
            .setOptions(PeerConnectionFactory.Options().apply {
                disableEncryption = false
                disableNetworkMonitor = true
            }).createPeerConnectionFactory()
    }

    private fun createPeerConnection(observer: PeerConnection.Observer): PeerConnection? {
        return peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(iceServer, observer)
    }

    private fun createDataChannel() {
        Log.d("RTCClient", "Creating data channel")

        // Initialize the data channel
        val initDataChannel = DataChannel.Init()
        Log.d("RTCClient", "DataChannel.Init() created")

        // Create the data channel
        val dataChannel = peerConnection?.createDataChannel("dataChannelLabel", initDataChannel)

        if (dataChannel != null) {
            Log.d("RTCClient", "Data channel created successfully: ${dataChannel.label()}")
            dataChannel.registerObserver(dataChannelObserver)
            Log.d("RTCClient", "Data channel observer registered")
        } else {
            Log.e("RTCClient", "Failed to create data channel: DataChannel is null")
        }
    }




    fun call(target: String) {
        if (peerConnection == null) {
            Log.e("RTCClient", "PeerConnection is not initialized.")
            return
        }
        createDataChannel()
        val mediaConstraints = MediaConstraints()
        mediaConstraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"))
//        mediaConstraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("RtpDataChannel","true"))

        peerConnection?.createOffer(object : SdpObserver {
            override fun onCreateSuccess(desc: SessionDescription?) {
                peerConnection?.setLocalDescription(object : SdpObserver {
                    override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription?) {

                    }

                    override fun onSetSuccess() {
                        val offer = hashMapOf(
                            "sdp" to desc?.description,
                            "type" to desc?.type
                        )

                        socketRepository.sendMessageToSocket(
                            MessageModel(
                                "create_offer", username, target, offer
                            )
                        )

                    }

                    override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String?) {
                    }

                    override fun onSetFailure(p0: String?) {
                    }


                }, desc)

            }

            override fun onSetSuccess() {
            }

            override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String?) {
            }

            override fun onSetFailure(p0: String?) {
            }
        }, mediaConstraints)
    }

    fun onRemoteSessionReceived(session: SessionDescription) {
        peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(object : SdpObserver {
            override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription?) {

            }

            override fun onSetSuccess() {
            }

            override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String?) {
            }

            override fun onSetFailure(p0: String?) {
            }

        }, session)

    }

    fun answer(target: String) {
        val constraints = MediaConstraints()
        constraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"))
//        constraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("RtpDataChannel","true"))

        peerConnection?.createAnswer(object : SdpObserver {
            override fun onCreateSuccess(desc: SessionDescription?) {
                peerConnection?.setLocalDescription(object : SdpObserver {
                    override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription?) {
                    }


                    override fun onSetSuccess() {
                        val answer = hashMapOf(
                            "sdp" to desc?.description,
                            "type" to desc?.type
                        )
                        socketRepository.sendMessageToSocket(
                            MessageModel(
                                "create_answer", username, target, answer
                            )
                        )

                    }

                    override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String?) {
                    }

                    override fun onSetFailure(p0: String?) {
                    }

                }, desc)
            }

            override fun onSetSuccess() {
            }

            override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String?) {
            }

            override fun onSetFailure(p0: String?) {
            }

        }, constraints)

    }

    fun addIceCandidate(p0: IceCandidate?) {
        peerConnection?.addIceCandidate(p0)
    }



    fun checkConnectionStatus(){
        if (peerConnection == null) {
            Log.e("PeerConnection", "PeerConnection is not initialized.");
            return;
        }
        // Check signaling state
        val signalingState: SignalingState = peerConnection!!.signalingState()
        Log.d("PeerConnection", "Signaling state: $signalingState")

        // Check ICE connection state
        val iceConnectionState: IceConnectionState = peerConnection!!.iceConnectionState()
        Log.d("PeerConnection", "ICE connection state: $iceConnectionState")

    }


}

And my ScoektRepositorty work perfectly.
My SocketRepository works perfectly. I want the ICE connection state for both Peer A and Peer B to be COMPLETED, and for the Data Channel to be open and able to send messages between peers.
